# .fadeIn() only seems to work after the content has been appended

Tags: jquery, append, fadein

Below is the script for a page I'm coding up. It works fine, but I'm seeing some really weird behavior with `.fadeIn(1000)`.

So, there's basically a display window in the center of the screen, and the left and right arrows on either side cycle through `div` elements containing a multiple choice question form.

That all works fine.

I want it to fade in nicely, and each item fades perfectly, but only after its been appended at least one time.

On the first cycle through, as you click, it's as if `.fadeIn` isn't even there, it just happens instantly. If you cycle through again though, it works fine.

The strange thing is, this works perfectly fine with a drop down menu I have on a different part of the site. On that site I use the same logic: a variable holds either a number or a string, the menu item click changes the variable's value, and calls for the function to run through a bunch of `if` statements until one is found true.

Here is my code for the problem site

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');

    var questionPosition = 0;

    function clearBox(){
        $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(1000)
        .appendTo('#question_holding')
    };

    function cycle(){
        if (questionPosition == 0) {
            $("#q0").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box')
            $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
        };

        if (questionPosition == 1) {
            $("#q1").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box')
            $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
        };

        if (questionPosition == 2) {
            $("#q2").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box')
            $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
        };

        if (questionPosition == 3) {
            $("#q3").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box')
            $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
        };

        if (questionPosition == 4) {
            $("#q4").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box')
            $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
        };
    }

    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
        questionPosition--;
        clearBox();
        cycle();
    });

    $('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
        questionPosition++;
        clearBox();
        cycle();
    });
});
```

Here is a sample of the code using the same logic of the working site, you'll see its pretty much the same idea.

```
function statusCheck(){
    if (status == 0){
        $("#instructions").fadeIn(1000).appendTo("#infoWindow");
        $("#instructions").removeClass("hide");
        $("#infoWindow").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
    } else{}

    if (status == 1){
        $("#worldGrid").fadeIn(1000).appendTo("#mapWindow");
        $("#worldGrid").removeClass("hide");
        $("#worldInfo").fadeIn(1000).appendTo("#infoWindow");
        $("#worldInfo").removeClass("hide");
        $("#infoWindow").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
    } else{}
```

I'm fairly new to code, but the only thing that pops out at me is that my original code was `if` `else` statements, then I figured out I really didn't need the `else`, so on this newer page I didn't include it.

Thoughts?

Comment: When you say you want "it" to fade in nicely, what is "it"? Do the arrows pick different `div` elements and you want the `div` elements to fade nicely?

Comment: Sorry, shoud have been more clear, 

So "it" are the Div elements,  each DIv contains a Form with a question and and multiple choice answers. 

The arrows do a simple ++; to the variable, and the cycle function appends the correct question and answer set according to the variables current status. 

I want "it" the Divs, to fade in nicely the first time, not after they've been cycled through once already. 

The first time through they Instantly appear in the Display box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Move your functions out of window load.
> Replace in `cycle()` function your `if` statements with `switch`. This way if `questionPosition` goes beyond values 0-4 to fall in the `default` code-block.
>
> Use `clearBox()` on load to have the 1000 ms delay from start.

```
function cycle(questionPosition){
            switch(questionPosition) {
               case 0:
                     $("#q0").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
               break;
               case 1:
                     $("#q1").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
               break;
               case 2:
                     $("#q2").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
               break;
               case 3:
                     $("#q3").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
               break;
               case 4:
                     $("#q4").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
               break;
               default:
                     $("#q0").fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#display_box');
                     $("#display_box").animate({scrollTop:0},500);
            }                  
    }
    function clearBox(){
    $("#display_box").children().fadeOut(1000).appendTo('#question_holding');
    }
    $(window).load(function() { 
    var questionPosition = 0;
    clearBox();
    $(".intro").appendTo('#display_box');    
    $('#leftarrow').on('click', function(){
        questionPosition--;
        clearBox();
        cycle();
    });   
    $('#rightarrow').on('click', function(){
        questionPosition++;
        clearBox();
        cycle();
    });   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Never make a bunch of numbered ID elements, ever. It is the worst possible way to do it. It is terrible.

The moment you feel yourself about to piece together the name of an element with the ID, **STOP**! Step away from the `id` attribute slowly and pick up a `class` attribute.

Always use a class name on anything that will occur multiple times, and select that selector and use `.length` to adapt to the count, and use `.eq(N)` to select the *N*th item.

A bunch of duplicated if statements is the worst way to implement something like this. You should refer to the questions numerically, and use `$('.questions').eq(N)` to select question N.

The issue is that you fade it before you append it somewhere.

```
var questions = $('.questions'),
    displayBox = $('#display_box');

...
function cycle() {
    questions.eq(questionPosition)
    .appendTo(displayBox)
    .fadeIn(1000);
    displayBox.animate({scrollTop:0}, 500);
}
```

You had a nice consistent structure to work with, but heavy repetition is not good. It is very error prone to have a lot of different lines that do almost the same thing. That is what variables are for. They hold values for placeholders.

And if you've been told that ID is "faster", you have been mislead. You don't make speed by hard-coding everything to fixed bug-prone names. You make speed by modifying the document in an efficient manner, avoiding forcing the browser to reflow, such as appending a lot of items to something that is visible. The time spent in the `$('.questions')` selector lookup at startup is an instant.

In fact, my code is far faster. Your code repeatedly does lookups into the page, mine does it once, in an instant, then never needs to look for any again.

If you use questions.length for the wrap around, then the code will also auto-magically handle any number of question elements found in the page.

Comment: Im literally a brand new and self taught coder, could you explain this to me a ittle better. 

This website is for a RPG, and it has its own "monster" index that is 120 bloody monsters long !  And each one is exactly this code, the Game maps page which is from the second box of code wasnt so bad, that only have 12-14 changing images. But the monster page is  one gigantic IF statement

I'd love a more efficient way of doing this, but I dont know how lol.

Comment: I showed how: 1) use a class name on the elements that need that behavior, 2) use `.each` to do them all, or `.eq(N)` to select one by number, and `.length` to detect the number of items. Example: `questions.length`.

Comment: Note how my code, at startup, does `questions = $('.questions');` and keeps it. That selects every element that has class "questions".

Comment: Thank you so much, i definitely appreciate your tips!

Comment: @LucianKain You should put it on github, then people can look at whole thing and/or even contribute improvements. If you got it from github to begin with, just go fork the project and you'll have your own version, for which you control the changes.